# Self drilling masonry screws?

Tags: screws

It’s true. I’m telling you I’ve seen them. It’s a masonry screw with the typical triangular tip seen on all masonry drill bits. I saw them in the van of one of the utility companies here in town and was blown away. I went to Fastenal and they didn’t have them. I googled it a little bit and couldn’t find anything. Does anyone know what I’m talking about and where I can buy these things? I’m sure they’re expensive but it’s worth to me to be able to skip the pre drilling step altogether.

Comment: Never seen or heard of them, I don't know it could ever work, the concrete dust has to have somewhere to go and the threads will not allow that to happen.

Comment: Call the utility company.

Answer (score 1):

you probably saw something like this

these are for metal, not masonary

[image]

Comment: http://eagle-tool.us/concrete-tool.html. It may be that they were using this tool that combines the drill and screw fastener in one tool